# Codeigniter local Ok mas no servidor 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá pessoal estou com um problema para abrir meu projeto em CI no servidor que uso;

minha config.

se eu usar /Welcome, por exemplo o CI acha a pagina normalmente, porém se eu usar algum dos meus controllers ele retorna 404;

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.meusite.com.br/novo';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

meu controler chama-se index e possui o $this->load->view('minhaview'); (tudo normal até aqui).

meu .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

mas mesmo assim o site não abre no meu servidor mas funciona normalmente no localhost.

Comment: tenta alterar a permissao do seu htaccess no servidor. Ja resolvi um problema assim fazendo isso.

Comment: Por acaso, se tentar acessar esse outro controller com o index.php ele funciona? por exemplo, http://www.meusite.com.br/novo/index.php/outrocontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique a primeira letra do nome de cada controler, se estiver em caixa baixa troque para caixa alta, exemplo: **w**elcome.php troque para **W**elcome.php. 
tive o mesmo problema essa semana ao subir uma aplicação no meu host.